# Average over multiple columns in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have following data:

| Cust_ID | Item_ID | Item_type | Item_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | Clothes | Jacket |
| 2 | 33 | Electronic | Phone |
| 1 | 22 | Clothes | Jacket |
| 1 | 22 | Clothes | Shirt |

I want to find out Average number of ITEM, per customer, per ITEM TYPE using DAX query in PowerBI

I tried with doing something like

```
avg_cust_item = AVERAGEX(VALUES(item_data[Item_Id]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE(item_data[Cust_Id])))
```

but it's pretty clear that this is not going to solve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put it all in a table, adding everything you need and select `COUNT` for `Item_ID`. If you don't have `Cust_ID` as a string, you'll have to change that to 'Don't summerize'. That'll give you this:

[image]

Comment: Would you help me with the DAX query as I don't follow everything clearly what you mean with this explanation.

Comment: You don't need to use DAX for something as simple as this. You can just add everything to a table and format the columns directly - like changing `Cust_ID` to not summerize, which it'll do if `Cust_ID` is stored as a number, and changing `Item_ID` to average rather than sum.